# Remote server log production.log is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Issue: log/production.rb file exists but is empty on production Rails 4.2 environment.

App root and permissions:

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 deploy deploy     4096 Mar  7 14:59 .
drwxrwxr-x 21 deploy deploy     4096 Mar  7 04:16 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 deploy deploy        0 Feb  6 17:13 .git_keep
-rw-rw-r--  1 deploy deploy 95833941 Mar  9 05:16 newrelic_agent.log
-rwxrwxrwx  1 deploy deploy       80 Mar  9 01:16 production.log
-rw-------  1 deploy deploy   129287 Mar  7 08:24 production.searchd.log
-rw-------  1 deploy deploy    93957 Mar  9 05:06 production.searchd.query.log
-rw-------  1 deploy deploy        5 Feb  7 10:37 production.sphinx.pid
```

**config/environments/production.rb**

```
# If you have no front-end server that supports something like X-Sendfile,
  # just comment this out and Rails will serve the files
  config.log_level = :info
  # Basic log config, for calls to Rails.logger.<level> { <message> }
  config.logger = Logger.new('log/production.log')
  # Formats log entries into: LEVEL MESSAGE
  # Heroku adds to this timestamp and worker/dyno id, so datetime can be stripped
  config.logger.formatter = ->(severity, datetime, progname, msg) { "#{severity} #{msg}\n" }

  # Lograge config, overrides default instrumentation for logging ActionController and ActionView logging
  config.lograge.enabled = true
```

Help please. Thank you for advance

Comment: What config are you using in production? What load balancer are you using? If you are using nginx check the access.log and error.log first.

Comment: I use nginx logs. But I want need logs in rails application

Comment: Can you check whether nginx logs are present or not? If they are present then you are getting the request. If not then you did not configure your system properly. If you logs are present then we will definitely know that the issue is rails configuration for production logs.

Comment: i checked nginx logs, yes, last log 10.03